# dependencyproperty.unsetvalue exception in multibinding with DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have bound my `DataGrid` to a list `SysRebarDefinitions` in my view model. At first everything is okay and the data is loaded as expected, but when I try to edit the cell. I get `dependencyproperty.unsetvalue` error in my converter. What can be the problem?

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SysRebarDefinitions}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Weight" 
                            Width="*">
            <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource RebarLengthAndDensityToWeightMultiConverter}" 
                                    StringFormat="{}{0:0.###}">
                    <Binding Path="StockLength"/>
                    <Binding Path="Weight"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Show the implementation of the converter. Probably has no proper implementation of `ConvertBack`.

Comment: @H.B. I have not implemented the `ConvertBack` part yet. But I debugged  and it seems the ConvertBack part doesn't execute at all. The Convert method is executed and the `object[] values` contains `dependencyproperty.unsetvalue`. The first time it works. It fails when I try to edit.

Comment: @H.B. I have googled it. It must be because of the binding and somehow finding the parent control bound but I don't know how to implement it in XAML.

Comment: Same behavior sometimes for me, in similar situation. The binding engine of WPF executes the converter multiple times to update UI and models, so I suggest you to immediately exits from the converter when any of values are UnSet value. I quite sure that some milliseconds later you re-enter in the converter with expected values. Can you try that?

Comment: @IgorDamiani It only happens when I try to edit it. It doesn't throw exceptions while displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got some red arrows for this question but I do not know why but here is the solution I found! Just check for the `UnsetValue` in the converter and return.

```
if (values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue ||
    values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It's because you did not post the relevant code, which is the converter implementation. Which i told you in the very first comment.

Comment: @H.B. You are right! But it is not in the `ConvertBack` part as you told me in your first comment.